# How to display the response from the php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

$ Here i am sending the php code the main function of this code is to fetch the data from the database and send it back to the ajax jquery $

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$database="testme";
$password="";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);

$data= mysql_select_db($database,$connect);

// executing the query
$identity=$_REQUEST['id'];

$query="SELECT * FROM student_demo WHERE id=1";
$getdata=mysql_query($query);

$get_row1=mysql_fetch_array($getdata);

$data1=array('value1' => $get_row1[0],
        'value2' => $get_row1[1],
        'value3' => $get_row1[2],
        'value4' => $get_row1[3]);

    print json_encode($data1);


?>
```

$ Now i am sending the Jquery ajax code which is receiving the response and than dislyaing the content in the div tag of the html$

```
$.ajax({
            url:'process.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#id").append(data.value1);   
                alert(data.value1); 
            }
    });
```

$Now the problem is that noting gets add to the #id field in the Html file$

Comment: where is `i` defined?

Comment: does alert show the content?

Comment: @MatteoRiva is right. i is nothing the way it is right now. Try appending just data

Comment: in alert(data) nothing gets displayed means no alert box pop up

Comment: what changes i should make to get the code working

Comment: As a side note, and without even mentioning the obsoleteness of mysql_ functions in php, using `mysql_fetch_array` together with `select *` and indexed access to fields is a cocktail that will explode in your face one day.

Comment: Comment the line `$("#id").append(data.value1);` and check whether you get the alert.

Comment: make sure there is a correct `#id` in your HTML, and make sure there is no missing closing tags or typos on tags

Comment: The first thing you need is to use try-catch in your code. That will tell you if and where is any error or exception being thrown. There are so many things that could go wrong where. Database linking, running sql query, '#id' element is inaccessible or does not exist at the moment of access. And you are also using the jquery ajax method that is deprecated as of version 1.7, you need to watch for that. If the pop-up is not displaying that could mean only two things. Either an error in PHP occurred and the control was not sent to success method. Or Javascript broke down.

Answer (score 0):

Add data in your `$data1` array like this

```
$data1=array('value1' => $get_row1[0],
    'value2' => $get_row1[1],
    'value3' => $get_row1[2],
    'value4' => $get_row1[3]);
```

And in AJAX response you can get the json encoded data like this

```
$.ajax({
        url:'process.php',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#id").append(data.value1);   
            alert(data.value1); 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
           alert(textStatus + errorThrown);
        }
});
```

Comment: sir nothing is happening...i am not even getting the alert message.

Comment: Are you able to see the ajax request in browsers console? or test the code by removing/commenting following code for some time
    $("#id").append(data.value1);

Comment: @user1334573 Have you tried the code by commenting this line `$("#id").append(data.value1);`? Are you getting the alert?

Comment: @user1334573 Ok. I am editing my code above. Make that change in the AJAX request. and let me know what you do you get. may be its not enter in 'success' block.

Answer (score 0):

ok, first thing you haven't used `$identity` anywhere. 
Anyways, when you get response in js variable data, then you need to parse that encoded string like 
`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( obj.0 );`

Try this may help you.

Comment: if you specify `datatype: 'JSON'` in the ajax call, jquery does the JSON parsing automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
$getdata=mysql_query($query);
$resultSet = array();
if($getdata){

    while($resultRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
        $resultSet[] = $resultRow;
    }
}
echo json_encode($resultSet);
```

Jvascript Code

```
$.ajax({
    url:'tt.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data)
    {                
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            // do your coding here
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var tmpRowData = data[i];
            $.each(tmpRowData, function(columnName, columnValue) {
            console.log(columnName+' = '+columnValue);
            });
        }); 
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: means what are the parameters which are being passed

Comment: I have updated the jQuery's each function in above code. Now Browser's Console must show the column name and it's value

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not directly answering your question. But it will help you with finding the issue.

Try to use google developer tool or firefox firebug add-on. Those will show you if you have any javascript errors.

Based on your code you can do following with relavant tools. First check whether your Ajax request is generating or not. If it's not generating you will probably have javascript error. If it's generating check the response you got.If you received proper JSON response you can check it by commenting the line `$("#id").append(data.value1);` Since you have added an alert it should work if you are getting the correct response.

If it's working check your DIV has named with the ID attribute correctly or any HTML syntax errors.

If you don't get proper response the issue is with the PHP code. Now try to debug your php code.

```
$get_row1=mysql_fetch_array($getdata);
print_r($get_row1);
exit;
```

Are you getting the data array printed as you required? If not it should probably an issue with your SQL or database.

You can check mysql error log and apache error log to find if there any PHP or mysql error occurred.Just follow few debugging, you will be able to find the issue your self, at least where the error occurred, client side or server side, with wich statement, If you find that the community will give you more support since everyone understand where the issue is.